# How to query remote procedure or view

Tags: sql-server-2012, remote-server

I have 2 server A and Server B(remote 3rd party) both SQL server 2012. We need to query the data from remote Server B, we are planning to use either view or stored procedure. The query contain multiple joins to fetch data from around 10 tables(minimum 10 tables is there in initial analysis may be more tables will be added in future).
If we are going to access the data through VIEW then we are going to write the below query
`SELECT * FROM view-name WHERE Column1 ='abc'`
My first question
Q1. I have a doubt whether this query will load all the data from table joined in the view and then the WHERE condition implement as in the VIEW definition we are not implementing the filter condition. If it is like that then this will be a performance issue, Please correct me if it is like this or not.
Q2. Which will has better performance a stored procedure or view.
Q3. How to call a remote stored procedure or View. linked server is not allowed.
 Does the 4 part `server.DB.Schema.SPorView name` will work.

I had search and find about OPENROWSET/OPENQUERY does it works without linked server.

Please let me know if need further clarification

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to avoid linked server or you cannot use linked server?

Comment: linked server option is not available...as the remote server is handled by other party they will not allow.

Comment: In my opinion you should use views on remote server, and query using [OPENROWSET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx). When you define `SELECT * FROM view WHERE...` this query will be sent to target and return result set will be restricted by your conditions. For more info please read [INSERT-EXEC and OPENQUERY](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html#INSERTEXEC)